# Menu Bar not Maximized When Main Window Maximized

Tags: qt, qmainwindow

In Qt 5.5.1 (Linux), I am showing main window in maximized state as:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

In the main window constructor, I call `CreateMenuBar` which simply creates some menu:

```
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
projectMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Project"));
...
```

When run, Main Window is shown at maximized state correctly but menu bar shortened as:

[image]

One strange behaviour is that if I normalized the window with clicking normalize button in window top then maximizing again does stretch the menu bar as it should be.

What am I missing?

Comment: What if you call `show()` before setting the window state?

Comment: @vahancho, It solves the problem. Can you write an answer with an explanation the logic behind? Cause it seemed not rational to me.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 16.04. Could be a Qt bug.

Comment: @aatwo, what is the Qt version?

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 using Qt 5.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to call `QMainWindow::show()` function before setting its state, i.e.:

```
[..]
w.show();
w.setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
```

I am not sure I know the exact reason of such behavior, but I guess that Qt performs incorrect layouting if you try to change its geometry without showing it. It may also depend on window manager you use.